# I'm trying to create an unordered list in php and display it to html file

Tags: php, html

I'm very new to PHP/Programming, so you can understand my frustration. Don't get me wrong I'm loving it.

My objective is to create an unordered list in PHP and display it in html.

I was able to successfully create the unordered list, and it shows up correctly.

My issue is when I try to display it to an HTML file using the `fopen();` & `fwrite();`.

The error i'm getting is that it only display the last three values in my array when I switch over to my .html file. My code is below, any advice is appreciated.

```
$colors = array (
      0 => array ("red", "black", "white"),
      1 => array ("yellow", "blue", "green"),
      2 => array ("orange", "grey", "pink"),
      3 => array ("purple", "brown", "clear"),
);

foreach ($colors as $value) {
    echo "<ul>";
    $couleur = "<li>". implode ("</li><li>", $value) ."</li>";
    echo $couleur;
    echo "</ul>";
}

$y = fopen ("list.html", "w");
fwrite ($y, $couleur);
```

Comment: is there a special reason you need to display this on the .html file and not directly display it from the .php file? you are also overwriting `$couleur` on each `foreach` iteration. try using `$couleur[] = ...`

Comment: Yes, you're overwriting `$couleur` every iteration of your loop. Define `$couleur` aas an empty string before the loop; don't echo inside the loop, but use `$couleur .= ...` to build your string

Comment: Change $couleur = to $couleur .= for concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing (`echo`), I think you want to store all data in a variable and write that data to file eventually. Otherwise you *will* see it when executing your PHP script, but it will not be written to file.

In your version, you're overwriting `$couleur` every iteration (as already pointed out by others), which explains why you only get the last array. You can append strings using the `.=` operator, which would make your code look like this, for example:

```
$colors = array (
    0 => array ("red", "black", "white"),
    1 => array ("yellow", "blue", "green"),
    2 => array ("orange", "grey", "pink"),
    3 => array ("purple", "brown", "clear"),
);

foreach ($colors as $value) {
    $couleur .= "<ul>";
    $couleur .= "<li>". implode ("</li><li>", $value) ."</li>";
    $couleur .= "</ul>";
}

$y = fopen ("list.html", "w");
fwrite ($y, $couleur);
```

Note that this provides you with four unordered lists. I'm not sure if that is what you want; you could also make one long list by moving the `<ul>` tags outside your loop:

```
$couleur = "<ul>";
foreach ($colors as $value) {
    $couleur .= "<li>". implode ("</li><li>", $value) ."</li>";
}
$couleur .= "</ul>";
```

Comment: awesome, thank you guys. Such a simple solution, just what i needed.